Closed subgroups of the additive group of adeles and their "modulo 2" quotients
I was wondering if in the adeles ring over $\mathbb{Q}$, viewed as an additive
group, any closed subgroup H is such that $((1/2)H)/H$ is finite or compact, where $1/2H$ is the group of adeles $x$ such that $2x \in H$. My first guess is to answer yes but in fact I noticed that classifying the closed subgroups of the adeles is not so obvious (at least for me)...
Any idea is welcome, thanks in advance!

So the answer seems to be yes, such a quotient is always finite. We can follow a reasonning similar to
Closed subgroups of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}\cong\prod_{p}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ as subsets?
If $H$ denotes a subset of the adèle ring $\mathbb{A}$, $h = (h_p)$ an element of $H$ with $h_p \in \mathbb{Q}_p$
for any place (finite prime or $\infty$ for the real component), I define $H^\perp$ to be the (closed) subgroup of
$\mathbb{A}$ defined as $\{h' = (h'_p) \in \mathbb{A} , 
h'_p.h_p  \in \mathbb{Z}_p ~~\forall p \leq \infty, ~~\forall h=(h_p) \in H \}$. When $H$ is a closed subgroup of
$\mathbb{A}$ one has $(H^\perp)^\perp = H$ (from Pontryagin duality).
If for a finite prime $p$ we write $h_p = p^{n(p,h)}z(p,h)$ with $z(p,h) \in \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$,
the condition $h'_p.h_p  \in \mathbb{Z}_p$
means that $n(h',p)  \geq -n(h,p)$ for all $p< \infty$ and $h \in H$, so that $H'$ is made of
any element $(h'_p)\in \mathbb{A}$ such that $n(h',p) \geq N'(p) = \max(-n(h,p),~~h\in H)$ where $N'(p)$ can possibly
be infinite, meaning that the $p$ component of $h'$ vanishes. In case $h_p$ is only $0$, that is to say $n(p,h)=\infty$ then
$n(h',p) \geq -\infty$ means that it can take any value and in that case $h'_p$ can be any element of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.
For the archimedean case, I denote by ${}_{a}\mathbb{Z}$ a closed
subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$, where $a$ is an extended real number, that is ${}_{a}\mathbb{Z} = a\mathbb{Z}$ when $a$ is finite
and different from $0$, ${}_{0}\mathbb{Z} = 0$ and ${}_{\infty}\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{R}$
(not to be confused with $\mathbb{Z}_{\infty} = \mathbb{Z}$). With this notation we have that
the condition $h'_\infty.h_\infty  \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $h_\infty$ describes a closed subgroup  ${}_{a}\mathbb{Z}$
of $\mathbb{R}$, gives that $h'_\infty$ describes the subgroup ${}_{a^{-1}}\mathbb{Z}$.
Therefore $H' = {}_{a^{-1}}\mathbb{Z}\times \prod_{p< \infty} p^{N'(p)}\mathbb{Z}_p$
($p^{-\infty}\mathbb{Z}_p = \mathbb{Q}_p$ by convention, only a finite number of $N'(p)$ can be equal to $-\infty$)
and since $(H^\perp)^\perp = H$ for a closed subgroup,
following the same reasonning we get that $H$ is also of this form, that is
$H = {}_{r}\mathbb{Z}\times\prod_{p< \infty} p^{N(p)}\mathbb{Z}_p$.
But now, when considering $1/2H$,
we have that $1/2{}_{r}\mathbb{Z}= {}_{r/2}\mathbb{Z}$ with the natural convention that $\infty/2 = \infty$,
$1/2p^{N(p)}\mathbb{Z}_p = p^{N(p)}\mathbb{Z}_p$ when $p>2$ since $1/2$ is in that case a unit padic integer, and
$1/2 (2^{N(2)}\mathbb{Z}_2) = 2^{N(2)-1}\mathbb{Z}_2$, and $(1/2{}_{r}\mathbb{Z})/{}_{r}\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$
for $r$ finite different from $0$, trivial otherwise, $(1/2p^{N(p)}\mathbb{Z}_p)/p^{N(p)}\mathbb{Z}_p$ is always trivial
for $p>2$ and $1/2 (2^{N(2)}\mathbb{Z}_2)/2^{N(2)}\mathbb{Z}_2 = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ if $-\infty < N(2)<\infty$, trivial otherwise.
Finally we get that $1/2H/H$ is a isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and is
therefore finite.
